# Dynamically changing property field in ExtJs Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, extjs, combobox

I am using a grid with a checkbox and a combobox. Right now I am trying to find a way to make the combobox multi select if the checkbox is checked in roweditor.

```
            var pEditing =
            Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing',
                    {
                        clicksToMoveEditor: 2,
                        errorSummary: false,
                        autoCancel: false,
                        listeners:
                        {
                            change: function (newValue, oldValue, eOpts)
                            {
                                if (newValue.value == true)
                                {
                                    this.down().down('grid').queryById('comboboxColumn').multiSelect = true;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    this.down().down('grid').queryById('comboboxColumn').multiSelect = false;
                                }
                                console.log("Checkbox Change Debug");
                             }
                        }
                   });
```

Grid creation code :

```
                                            {
                                                renderer: renderCheckbox,
                                                itemId: 'checkboxColumn',
                                                header: 'Checkbox',
                                                width: 100,
                                                sortable: false,
                                                dataIndex: 'ddCheckbox',
                                                editor: {
                                                    xtype: 'checkbox',
                                                    cls: 'x-grid-checkheader-editor',
                                                    listeners:{
                                                        change: function (newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
                                                            pEditing.fireEvent('change',newValue, oldValue, eOpts);
                                                        }
                                                    },   
                                                },

                                            },
                                            {
                                                header: 'Speed',
                                                dataIndex: 'ddSpeed',
                                                itemId: 'comboBoxColumn',
                                                width: 125,
                                                editor:
                                                        {
                                                            xtype: 'combo',
                                                            editable: false,
                                                            multiSelect: false,
                                                            store:
                                                                    [
                                                                        ['1', '1'],
                                                                        ['2', '2'],
                                                                        ['3', '3'],
                                                                        ['4', '4'],
                                                                        ['5', '5']

                                                                    ]
                                                        }
                                            }
```

Right now the event is firing off and I can see the debug message printed to the log. However the multiselect property is not persisting after the event is fired. Is there any easy way to change the property of this combobox in the row? For example, if there are 3 rows in the grid, row one can have the checkbox checked, and multiple values selected while row two has the checkbox unchecked and only one selection can be made?  I know I can find the index of the checkbox selected by using in the change function.

```
this.down().down('grid').getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].getData()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"multiselect" property is not persisting because, your below code is not yet reach till combo box control.

```html
this.down().down('grid').queryById('comboboxColumn').multiSelect = true;
```

As per your code, combo box control is under 'comboBoxColumn' item. So specify "itemID" for combo box like

```html
xtype: 'combo',
editable: false,
multiSelect: false,
itemId: 'comboBoxItems',    
store:[....]
```

Then, try below code

```html
this.down().down('grid').queryById('comboboxColumn').queryById('comboBoxItems').multiSelect = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

> As you using [RowEditing](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing.html) plugin

In [checkbox](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Checkbox.html)  on value [change](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.form.field.Checkbox.html#event-change) event you will get 4 parameters  `change:function(field, newValue, oldValue, eOpts)`

**1)** Usign `field` parameter you will get your selected row(`roweditor`) like this `field.up()`.

**2)** Using this `roweditor` you can use `roweditor.down()` method and get your `combo`.

**3)** After that getting your component(`combo`) and using second parameter `newValue` you can set multiSelect like `combo.multiSelect = newValue`

> Here is I have created an [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/295e) demo.

Hope this will help you to achieve your solution or requirement

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [{
        name: 'Lisa',
        email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-111-1224'
    }, {
        name: 'Bart',
        email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1234'
    }, {
        name: 'Homer',
        email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1244'
    }, {
        name: 'Marge',
        email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
        phone: '555-222-1254'
    }]
});

// The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data: [{
        "abbr": "AL",
        "name": "Alabama"
    }, {
        "abbr": "AK",
        "name": "Alaska"
    }, {
        "abbr": "AZ",
        "name": "Arizona"
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [{
        header: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        editor: 'textfield'
    }, {
        header: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            allowBlank: false
        }
    }, {
        header: 'Multiple',
        dataIndex: 'multiple',
        sortable:false,
        menuDisabled:true,
        flex: 0.5,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'checkboxfield',
           // checked:true,
            listeners: {
                change: function (field, newValue) {
                    var combo = field.up().down('#state');
                    combo.reset();
                    combo.multiSelect = newValue
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        header: 'States',
        dataIndex: 'states',
        flex: 1,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'combo',
            store: states,
            itemId: 'state',
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'name',
            multiSelect:true,
            valueField: 'abbr',
            filterPickList: false,
            listeners:{
                afterrender:function(){
                    this.multiSelect=false;
                }
            }
        }
    }],
    selModel: 'rowmodel',
    plugins: {
        ptype: 'rowediting',
        clicksToEdit:1
    },
    height: 200,
    width: '100%',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```